# JavaFX: How to stop TextFLow objects from Wrapping

Tags: javafx-8, word-wrap, textflow

I using TextFlow object as the graphic node for a CheckBoxTextItem (from controlsFX). 
If the TextFlow object is longer the width of the tree view, it gets wrapped. How can I stop the wrapping? or set something like an Ellipsis String-- like what you can do with Labels?

The text flow object is made up of Text objects.

Comment: What's weird is, I have the exact opposite situation. I want it to wrap to the available width, but it refuses to wrap at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [TextFlow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html) documentation:

> The wrapping width of the layout is determined by the region's current
>   width. It can be specified by the application by setting the
>   textflow's preferred width. If no wrapping is desired, the application
>   can either set the preferred with to Double.MAX_VALUE or
>   Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE.

So, to stop a TextFlow from wrapping:

```
textFlow.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
```

Comment: Hi jewelsea, It works better. but I am still getting a text-wrap in certain situations. I might just force clip text so it does go beyond a certain range.

Comment: I think it works in all cases if you add `textFlow.setMinWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);`

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap a textflow in a scrollpane because scrollpane layout is calculated by its child nodes .